# how to get div tag from aspx page when use user control

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem when I use user control to get div tag from aspx page that contain my user control.
I have a div in aspx page: `<div id="divMask" class="divMask" runat="server"></div>`
and in my user control I want get div ID to add attribute "onclick" but I can't get it.

My aspx page:

```
<div id="dvConfirmAcc" runat="server" style="display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 2000; top: 155px; left: 400px;">
      <uc1:ConfirmAccount ID="ucConfirmAccount" runat="server" />
</div>
<div id="divMask" class="divMask" runat="server"></div>
```

In my user control ucConfirmAccount:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url =  "some url";
    [I want get divMask at here].Attributes.Add("onclick", "closeMessage('" + url + "')");
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access div defined in `Page` directly from `UserControl`, instead you have to use `Page.FindControl` method

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.UI.Control divMask = (System.Web.UI.Control)this.Page.FindControl("divMask");
        if (divMask is System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)
        {
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl htmlCtrl = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)divMask;            
            htmlCtrl.Attributes[..] = "...";
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for help. I can get it but how do I add attribute for it?

Comment: sorry I can't understand this line:
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl htmlCtrl = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)p;
what is "p"????

Comment: sorry, p should be replaced with divMask here

Comment: Oh thank you very much. But when I use "this.Page" i get null value. If I replace with Parent.FindControl I can get it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful if you could post some code so we could help you more.

Try reading these links, they might help you in your problem:

[.NET In Search Of ASP.Net Controls](http://odetocode.com/articles/116.aspx) 
[ASP.NET 2.0 MasterPages and FindControl()](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Apr/09/ASPNET-20-MasterPages-and-FindControl)
[Find Control in Multiview](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FindControlInMultiview.aspx)