# Can't find HTML tags in code behind under impersonation

Tags: html, asp.net, ihttphandler

I have an aspx page that inherits the **IHttpHandler** class. 
On page load I issued a call to an Impersonation class in which it renders the content under a different username than that currently logged in. But the problem is when impersonated I call a function back on the code behind in the aspx page that needs to access a div tag in order to insert content to it via an object tag and it doesn't find the tag anymore. Any clue as to why? Or to how am I able to build tags from the code behind in such a situation?

The impersonation function I used is based off of : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107940/Back-to-Basic-ASP-NET-Runtime-Impersonation.aspx

And this is the function that is called when impersonated *within* my aspx page:

```
    public void FUNCTION() //This is called from the impersonation function above
    {
        report = Session[Document];
        string url = "http://localhost/PATH" + report.toString();

        HtmlGenericControl objReport = new HtmlGenericControl();
        objReport.TagName = "object";
        objReport.Attributes.Add("data", url);
        Control cntrl = Page.FindControl("objReportFrame");
        if (cntrl != null)
            cntrl.Controls.Add(objReport);
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the code and give a worked example. otherwise people can only guess.

Comment: @ADyson I added my code above, if you may kindly look at it again and advise me.

Comment: Try Parent.FindControl see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396321/how-to-get-div-tag-from-aspx-page-when-use-user-control

Comment: Or don't use Page and just use FindControl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265103/find-div-tag-from-code-behind

Comment: @puppet Just using FindControl worked but now I get thrown an error : "Cannot get inner content of objReportFrame because the contents are not literal"

Comment: Ahh I added embed in the url and it works !